# How to update a function in react when firing off onChange event

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that filters the customers based on their levels (intermediate, beginner ), I'm passing this function through a component that has  React select to filter my Data(async)

The filter is working only when I filter the first time but when I choose another value to filter it gave me a blank page?

I tried useEffect to keep it updated but it not working

Do you have any suggestions?

//APP.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import YogaCourses from "./components/YogaCourses/YogaCourses";
import Loading from "./components/IsLoading/Loading";
import LevelsFilter from './components/LevelsFilter/LevelsFilter';

//API to fetch the data
const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tayarthouail/8fb14fe117fdd718ceabd6ee05ed4525/raw/8c86c4bb89fc51667ba0578b2dcba14a0b21f08c/Yoga-courses-api.json';

function App() {
  
  //states
  const [yogaCourses, setYogaCourses] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);


  //Filter by Levels 
  const filterLevels = (level) => {
    const getLevels = yogaCourses.filter((singleLevel)=> singleLevel.level === level.value);
    setYogaCourses(getLevels);
  }

  //Function to fetch the data from the API
  const GetCourses = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const {data} = response;
    return data;
  }

//UseEffect to run the function on every render
  useEffect(()=> {
    const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
      const result = await GetCourses();
      setYogaCourses(result);
      console.log(result);
      setLevels(Array.from(new Set(result.map((result)=> result.level))));
    } 
    GetCoursesYoga();
  }, []);

  //check if the we got response
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(yogaCourses.length > 0) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [yogaCourses])
  

  if(isLoading) {
    return (
      <Loading/>
    )
  } 
  else {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="title">
                <h2>YOUR PRACTICE REIMAGINED</h2>
            </div>
        <LevelsFilter levels={levels} filterLevels={filterLevels}/>
        <YogaCourses yogaCourses= {yogaCourses}/>
      </main>
      );
  }

  
}

export default App;
```

//LevelsFilter component

```
 import React from 'react';
    import Select from 'react-select';
    
    import './LevelsFilter.css';
    
    const LevelsFilter = ({levels, filterLevels}) => {
        const option = levels.map((level)=> ({value : level, label: level}));
        return (
        <div>
            <Select
            options ={option}
            className="select-option"
            placeholder={"Type..."}
            onChange={filterLevels}
            />
        </div>
        )
    } 
    
    
    export default LevelsFilter;
```

Comment: What is `setYogaCourses` function? Please include all relevant code. This should include the `setYogaCourses` callback function and the parent/ancestor component rendering `LevelsFilter` and passing the `levels` and `filterLevels` props. What debugging have you done in looking into why you've a blank page? Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is not a complete example. The most relevant function, `setYogaCourses` is never explained anywhere. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: FIrst guess: `setYogaCourses` modifies the `yogaCourses` directly, where it should use a [state hook setter](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) instead.

Comment: I just shared with you guys all the element needed :D sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are replacing your state with the filtered data and subsequent filtering filters from there, so you only ever reduce your data.

## Solution

I suggest storing an active filter state (i.e. `level`) and do the filtering inline when rendering so you skip the issue of stale/bad state.

```
function App() {
  //states
  const [yogaCourses, setYogaCourses] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);
  const [level, setLevel] = useState('');

  const levelChangeHandler = ({ value }) => {
    setLevel(value);
  }

  //Filter by Levels 
  const filterLevels = (level) => {
    return yogaCourses.filter(
      (singleLevel) => level ? singleLevel.level === level : true
    );
  }

  ...
  

  if(isLoading) {
    return (
      <Loading/>
    )
  } 
  else {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="title">
          <h2>YOUR PRACTICE REIMAGINED</h2>
        </div>
        <LevelsFilter levels={levels} onChange={levelChangeHandler}/>
        <YogaCourses yogaCourses={filterLevels(level)}/>
      </main>
      );
  }
}
```

LevelsFilter

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

import './LevelsFilter.css';

const LevelsFilter = ({ levels, onChange }) => {
    const option = levels.map((level)=> ({value : level, label: level}));
    return (
    <div>
        <Select
        options ={option}
        className="select-option"
        placeholder={"Type..."}
        onChange={onChange}
        />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution Drew, but I didn't understand why did you replace filterLevels in the origin components <YogaCourses yogaCourses= {yogaCourses}/> by <YogaCourses yogaCourses={filterLevels(level)}/> because the first one is from where I got all the data and display it in the dom and you replace it by a function ?

Comment: @DavidJay The `App` component is holding all the state, and controls updates, so it has the sources of truth. `Levelsfilter` is stateless and now just calls back with the current selected `level` option, and the filter value is applied inline to pass a filtered `yogaCourses` array to the `YogaCourses` component. The filtered array is what is considered derived state, since it is derived from the array and filter values, so it shouldn't also be stored in state.

Comment: Great explanation, the filter is working but  since I replace yogacourse with the function Levelsfilter(level), Initially I have no data displayed in UI until a filter, the idea is that I want to keep the initial data from the first response of the API then filter it based on the level :) what do you think ?

Comment: @DavidJay Ah, I see. You can update the filter callback to return true if there is a falsey filter value, i.e. `(singleLevel) => level ? singleLevel.level === level : true`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Drew, I learned a lot from you, I'm a beginner as a developer, What would be your advices or practices for all beginners to be better at javascript and react or problems solving :D !

Comment: @DavidJay No worries, we all start from the same place. Read (and re-read, and re-read) documentation, I've been in React/Javascript for *almost* 4 years and I continue to find and learn new things. Problem solving... I think learning how to break a problem down into trivial parts to solve for is the pattern. If you meant debugging, then again, trying to simplify/reduce the complexity of the area of the bug will help. Reducing the surface area of a bug helps you isolate what ***is*** and what ***isn't*** triggering a bug.

Comment: I appreciate your time and I will really take your advice into consideration.Big THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You need a copy state.
Your code is replacing the data source with filtered data. When you first time selects the option then your state replaces it with that one and you no longer have previous state data. On the second time, you don't have data that why it's blank on-screen.

Just copy and replace the below app.js code:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import YogaCourses from "./components/YogaCourses/YogaCourses";
import Loading from "./components/IsLoading/Loading";
import LevelsFilter from './components/LevelsFilter/LevelsFilter';

//API to fetch the data
const url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tayarthouail/8fb14fe117fdd718ceabd6ee05ed4525/raw/8c86c4bb89fc51667ba0578b2dcba14a0b21f08c/Yoga-courses-api.json';

function App() {
  
  //states
  const [yogaCourses, setYogaCourses] = useState([]);
  const [filteredYogaCourses, setFillteredYogaCourses] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);

  //Filter by Levels 
  const filterLevels = (level) => {
    const getLevels = yogaCourses.filter((singleLevel)=> singleLevel.level === level.value);
    setFillteredYogaCourses(getLevels);
  }

  //Function to fetch the data from the API
  const GetCourses = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    const {data} = response;
    return data;
  }

//UseEffect to run the function on every render
          useEffect(()=> {
            const GetCoursesYoga = async () => {
              const result = await GetCourses();
              setYogaCourses(result);
              setLevels(Array.from(new Set(result.map((result)=> result.level))));
            } 
            GetCoursesYoga();
          }, []);
    
  //check if the we got response
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(yogaCourses.length > 0) {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [yogaCourses])
  

  if(isLoading) {
    return (
      <Loading/>
    )
  } 
  else {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="title">
                <h2>YOUR PRACTICE REIMAGINED</h2>
            </div>
        <LevelsFilter levels={levels} filterLevels={filterLevels}/>
        <YogaCourses yogaCourses= {filteredYogaCourses}/>
      </main>
      );
  }

  
}

export default App;
```

I hope it will work, if not then please debug it because I haven't tested it but the idea will be same. :)